# Making uppercase in natbib "dcu"

Tags: natbib

How can i replace first letter of each word of bibliography with uppercase in  with format dcu?[image]

For example I want to transform 'PhD thesis' with 'PhD Thesis' automaticly or 'conference on Winter simulation' with 'Conference on Winter  Simulation'.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Well, you can't: If `PhD thesis` is written in the `.bib` file or in the style, it will be output like that. As well, please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out how to solve it when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With `biblatex`, you can customise bibliography predefined strings such as PhD thesis.

Comment: I don't know `natbib`, but you could make a copy of `dcu.bst`  and edit that.  Two things come to mind regarding edits to that file: 1) strings like `"PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull` can be changed to `"PhD Thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull`; and 2) strings like `"t" change.case$` capitalize only the first word... making it `"u" change.case$` instead will make the item upper-cased on each word.  The argument the change-case is referring to is the field that just precedes the `"t"` or `"u"`, such as `type`.  That clues you in on which cases need changing.